# Ошибка при git Pull Tortoise

Tags: git

Пытаюсь получить pull.
Появляется ошибка.

[image: Ошибка]

Только создал репозиторий, он пустой.
Как исправить?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: сделайте хотя-бы один `commit` , `push` сначала.

Comment: Вы были правы. Сделал и все заработало